# vim shift-k puts vim to background

Tags: ubuntu, vim

When I try to use the shift-k (`man` page view function of `vim`), `vim` goes to background, and I have to run `fg` to put it to foreground. I tried installing *man page viewer plugin*, but even with that, the same behavior happens. Is this the way it is supposed to work, or am I missing some `.vimrc` setting to come back to `vim` when `man` exits ?
(tried `let $PAGER=''` as well)

on Ubuntu(GNOME terminal), vim 7.3.

Comment: You are in a terminal window, how do you expect to run `man something` if Vim doesn't go to the background?

Comment: Ok, I got the offending line of `.vimrc` - this one `set shell=/bin/bash\ -i` , this was making `vim` not give me the prompt to just hit `ENTER` and come back to `vim` after viewing the `man` page!.

Answer (score 0):

The following line makes `vim` not prompt after quitting `man`:

```
  set shell=/bin/bash\ -i
```

I removed this and now I get the expected behavior, with the built-in `man` viewer, as well as the `Man` plugin.